# Beautifulsoup - why arent the images im scraping saving?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im iterating through and scraping images off a website... but for some reason the "write" isn't working and saving the image.  Am I supposed to declare a directory to save them to or something? here's my request.  Im using python 2.7

```
for img in imgs:
    image = img['href']
    img_url = my_url + image
    resource = urllib.urlretrieve(img_url)
    resource = resource[0]
    output = open(resource, "wb")
    output.write(resource)
    output.close()
```

Comment: Try calling open with a filename as the first argument

Answer (score 2):

You're working too hard!  `urlretrieve` will already have written the file to disk, all you need to do is copy it to somewhere more permanent.

```
filename,headers = urllib.urlretreive(img_url)
import shutil
shutil.copy(filename, "/path/to/somewhere")
```

But to answer your question about what is going on...

```py
resource = urllib.urlretrieve(img_url) # the file is on disk at /tmp/foobar
resource = resource[0]   # resource now contains "/tmp/foobar"
output = open(resource, "wb")  # oops!  You just opened "/tmp/foobar" for writing, which clears the file
```